# How to validate a PayPal webhook JSON message?

Tags: paypal

I am integrating PayPal subscriptions in a Django project.  I have it working well but I'm thinking it could be possible that someone malicious can simulate a webhook call and get a free subscription. Currently I have no way to verify if the webhook really comes from PayPal.

In other payment systems I could set a secret word in the call (from the service provider) and then in the app server validate the call through the secret word.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible ways...

1. Post it back to PayPal, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature
2. Check the cryptographic signature, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/notification-messages/
3. Include a `custom_id` in the original transaction, which will be returned, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request

Just don't use one of the PayPal-*-SDKs, since they are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. I was focused on the post body and didn't notice there was additional information in the headers. I've been trying the validation from paypal through the post request. Python requests don't seem to work. I get a 405 constantly :/

Comment: You are using the wrong HTTP verb, e.g. get instead of post

Comment: I'm really using post like so: requests.post(cert_url, data=data)

Comment: Wrong URL then, that's not what you post to

Comment: I've changed the url to: www.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232535/discussion-between-jaime38130-and-preston-phx).